# Excel VBA Autofilter using array - multiple values in same column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, autofilter

I feel like the answer is out there, but after lots of searching and experimenting, I am still coming up short.

So can see in the first image that column O had a comma separated list of values.  I would like my routine to filter the data on column A using the entire list when the user double click on the cell containing the list.

[image: before running routine]

My code reads:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("O:O")) Is Nothing Then
    Sheet1.Cells.AutoFilter 'clear existing filters
    Dim idArray() As String
    idArray = Split(Target.Value, ",") 'store cell contents in array
    Dim newIDArray(0 To 100) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(idArray)
     newIDArray(i) = """" & CStr(idArray(i)) & """"   'wrap elements with quotes ... not sure if needed
    Next
    Sheet1.Range("$A$8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=newIDArray
End If

Cancel = False
End Sub
```

However the result is the following image.  I looks like it is taking the filter in column A, deselecting All and showing results .... it is not using the values from the comma delimited list at all.

Any thoughts on what is happening?  Thanks for reading.

[image: after running double clicking cell]

Comment: I would debug this by checking the values of your final array before filtering. There is likely something wrong with the way you have loaded it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my setup:

- The comma separated values correspond to `Range("J1:J3")`
- The range to filter correspond to `Range("A1:A18")`

Please see correct way to appropriately size (`ReDim`) an array and how to add values to it below

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Arr          'Array to SPLIT string
Dim i As Long    'Index to loop through Arr
Dim Filt         'Array to filter range

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J1:J3")) Is Nothing Then
    Arr = Split(Target, ",")
    ReDim Filt(LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr))
        For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            Filt(i) = CStr(Arr(i))
        Next i
    Range("A1:A18").AutoFilter 1, Filt, xlFilterValues
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I removed the filter clear at beginning just for solution.

Comment: @Saladsamurai you may also add one condition e.g.  "And Len(Target.Value) > 0" after "If Not Intersect..." to prevent error if someone will click empty cell, or add more advanced check for proper Target values

Comment: True @RafałB - if OP limits the intersect to a range rather an entire column, the check may not be necessary but it def doesn’t hurt to have it!