# Excel Autofilter on cell separated by semicolon

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do exactly what is [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599453/excel-vba-autofilter-using-array-multiple-values-in-same-column), but not on double clicking a cell. I am trying to assign the event to a button on another sheet. Keeping getting an "object required" error and cant figure out why.

```
Dim Arr          'Array to SPLIT string
Dim i As Long    'Index to loop through Arr
Dim Filt         'Array to filter range
Sheet2.Cells.AutoFilter
Arr = Split(Sheet2.Range("g2"), ";")
ReDim Filt(LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr))
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Filt(i) = CStr(Arr(i))
    Next i
Sheet2.Range("z5:z5000").AutoFilter 25, Filt, xlFilterValues
```

Comment: What's your full code?  `Target` in a `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` code refers to the cell being double-clicked. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @BigBen so i have a button on sheet1 and trying to run this code onclick. I guess my question is what should i replace "Target" with to make this code work when click the button?

Comment: Get rid of the `If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet2.Range("b4:Ad5000")) Is Nothing Then` and change the `Target` in `Arr = Split(Target, ";")` to `Range("A1").Value`. Change the range reference as needed.

Comment: If you want to assign to a button, right-click the button and assign macro.

Comment: @BigBen ok, i implemented your suggestion and i dont get the error anymore. However, it doesn't filter correctly even though i have the ranges setup. My heading is from B4:AD4. The filter filters out the data correctly in col25, but the filter hides the heading and starts from the first row. Weird

Comment: @SJR Thats the easy part which works fine for me :p

Comment: Don't start your filter in row 5.

Comment: @BigBen ok i figured it out. i removed the auto filter clearing and modified this part of the code Sheet2.Range("z4") and it works fine now. Can you please post your comment as an answer so that i can give you the credit?

Comment: You can just self-answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @BigBen, i was able to overcome the error. Here is the working piece of code should anyone else need help:

```
 Dim Arr          'Array to SPLIT string
 Dim i As Long    'Index to loop through Arr
 Dim Filt         'Array to filter range
 Arr = Split(Sheet2.Range("g2"), ";")
 ReDim Filt(LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr))
 For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    Filt(i) = CStr(Arr(i))
 Next i
 Sheet2.Range("z4").AutoFilter 25, Filt, xlFilterValues
```